# Is there a workaround for this: Flash CS6 + IOS + TLF + Air 16?

Tags: flash, air, adobe, tlf

Knowing that: Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support, so AIR 4 will be useless

Flash CC does not support TLF, we are using Flash CS6

Yes, we have to use TLF for right to left languages (Other solutions wont work...)

Air 4 sdk works fine, but unfortunately it does not support 64-bit, we will be using Air 16 beta

Is there a workaround for this? Flash CS6 + IOS + TLF + Air 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed in AIR 16 beta:
12/15/2014 - Beta - AIR 16.0.0.245 Runtime and SDK

Fixed Issues:
[iOS]TLF text fields in Flash CS6 not getting updated. (3839544)